# Is it possible to save a file that shows up in the files app in an iPad Swift playgrounds app

Tags: swift, ipad, swift-playground, files-app

I can't seem to add an info.plist file so I‘m not sure I can save to iCloud, is there any other way to store a file and have it accessible from the files app on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible, but it isn‘t intended:  https://rambo.codes/posts/2021-12-28-a-document-based-app-in-swift-playgrounds-for-ipad/